# Oracle encountered an error adding a table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
        CREATE TABLE "EDS"."ESBPROCDOC" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY key Sequence COMMENT'自增主键', 
            "PROCNAME" VARCHAR(36) not NULL COMMENT'处理器名称',
            "PROCCODE" NUMBER(10,0) unique COMMENT'处理器对应数字',
            "PROCDESC" CLOB COMMENT'处理器描述',
            "PROCVAL" CLOB COMMENT'处理器值解释',
            "EXTDPARAM" CLOB COMMENT'扩展参数解释',
            "IS_DELETED" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 0 COMMENT'逻辑删除',
            "CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP COMMENT'创建表时间',
    "UPDATED_AT" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '修改表时间'
            USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DHERP"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DHERP"
```

Is there a problem with the SQL statement I wrote? Why did I report the error ORA-00907: missing right parentage? Thank you

Found errors and able to execute correctly

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is **invalid** for Oracle, as far as I can tell.

I fixed `create table` and removed storage info; Oracle will handle it itself quite well so - unless you really, *really* want to specify all that - go for it, just make sure that syntax is correct.

Checking available tablespaces:

```
SQL> SELECT tablespace_name FROM user_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
USERS
```

Create table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE esbprocdoc
  2  (
  3     id           NUMBER (10, 0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  4     procname     VARCHAR (36) NOT NULL,
  5     proccode     NUMBER (10, 0) UNIQUE,
  6     procdesc     CLOB,
  7     procval      CLOB,
  8     extdparam    CLOB,
  9     is_deleted   NUMBER (10, 0) DEFAULT 0,
 10     created_at   TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP,
 11     updated_at   TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP
 12  )
 13  TABLESPACE users;

Table created.
```

Comments are to be created separately:

```
SQL> COMMENT ON TABLE esbprocdoc IS 'PROC-related data';

Comment created.

SQL> COMMENT ON COLUMN esbprocdoc.id IS 'Primary key column';

Comment created.

SQL> COMMENT ON COLUMN esbprocdoc.procname IS 'Procedure name';

Comment created.

SQL>
```